# Access Date Time convert to string. Time is stored as Military, Don't want to convert

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am writing a SQL query for MS Access.

The two fields are DateTime. The start/end time are 22:30/6:30

When I run the following query

```
SELECT cDate(Format(table1.BeginTime,"hh:mm")),
```

I get 10:30 PM instead of 22:30. I do not want to convert to 12hrs format. How do I keep the Miliary time format?

Comment: `cDate` returns a date which does not _have_ a format.  The format  comes whenever you _display_ the value.  If it's just in the debugger then you don;t need to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

So I tried a few things in Access 2013 and it seems that @Bjones has a point.

In SQL Server `Format` is a clr .net function and `format(date, 'hh:mm')` will be 12 hour and `Format(date, 'HH:mm')` will be 24 hour.

But as @Bjones pointed out there may be some question of how your original column is held as text or date or time.....  And what I have concluded after trying is that your order of functions is wrong.

```
cDate(Format(table1.BeginTime,"HH:mm"))
```

`cDate` transforms the content to a date but it doesn't format it.

So

```
FORMAT(cDate(table1.BeginTime), "hh:mm")
```

or

```
FORMAT(cDate(table1.BeginTime), "HH:mm")
```

or

```
FORMAT(cDate(table1.BeginTime), "Short Time")
```

should give you what you want if the time is stored as text. If stored as date time you can just drop the cDate all together and stay with

```
FORMAT(table1.BeginTime, "Short Time")
```

as @Bjones answered.

Comment: Lower case `hh` works perfectly fine for me to get 24hr in MS Access 2010

Comment: @bjones good catch I acutally didn't know that Access would treat it the same because c# and SQL don't, so I just learned.  However, the order of the functions was the real culprit because cDate is what gets the 12 hour format and it was the outer most function.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to get rid of is the cDate function as your fields are already in DateTime format.

```
SELECT Format(table1.BeginTime,"hh:nn")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell what the result of the query is intended for.

If you need the date *value* and to *view* this in 24 hour format, use:

```
Select table1.BeginTime
```

and apply a Format property for the column of *h:nn* or *hh:nn*

If you need the date formatted as a string in 24 hour format, use:

```
Select Format(table1.BeginTime, "hh:nn")
```

and no Format is needed.

In any case, even though the format string h:*mm* will work, do use h:*nn* or hh:*nn*, as *m* is for the month.